# Carousel with Bootstrap and Django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to implement a simple Carousel with Bootstrap in a Django project.
Somehow the loop works but only the active is shown, I cant go to the next and prev image.

[The carousel-items are greyd out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N82H6.png)

```
<!--Carousel-->
<div class='row'>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      {% if labelimages %}
      {% for image in labelimages %}
        <div class="carousel-{% if forloop.first %}active{% else%}item{% endif %}">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ image.url }}" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ image.url }}" alt="Third slide">
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Django seems to be working fine. I suggest you check your css/js.

Comment: My bad...
Bootstrap tag is "carousel-item active" and not "carousel-active" :)